# Gracefully stopping ASP.NET Core Web App (from within Visual Studio debugger), an IHostedService-related question

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I am totally new to ASP.NET Core so I am probably missing something by 50 miles because I've spent 3 hours on this to no avail.

I've made a Web App from within VS 2017, hosted by Kestrel which runs under IIS Express (which is all *default* when you make a new web app). When I press F5 the app fires up, my Chrome browser opens up and I see the 'hello world'-esque output. When I close this browser window the app terminates.

Now, I need some tasks going on in the background and I need these tasks to have cleanup logic - I found that `IHostedService` allows me to do this.

The documentation states:

> When you register an IHostedService, .NET Core will call the StartAsync() and StopAsync() methods of your IHostedService type during application start and stop respectively.

I have done:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHostedService<MyBackgroundService>();
}
```

And the service starts as expected, everything is fine. Extremely simple stuff. But it never stops, not gracefully at least.

When I close that auto-started browser window, my app closes along with it but this method in my `IHostedService` service:

```
public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    ...
}
```

Is never called.

I have tried the [example provided in documentation](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/host/hosted-services/samples/2.x/BackgroundTasksSample-WebHost) and it exhibits the same issue - the cleanup is never done when I try it in VS.

I have noticed a peculiar information from an output channel called "ASP.NET Core Web Server":

```
BackgroundTasksSample> Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

It's obviously some redirection from the console as this app appears to be a console app in the first place. So I wonder if VS is, by seemingly hiding the console from me, preventing me from performing the graceful shut down of my app?

I also noticed a little IIS Express tray icon which lists any apps I've ran and it has a Stop button which doesn't seem to do anything. I assume IIS Express is here simply acting as some kind of a proxy.

I am dumbfounded, especially since I seem to be the only one having this problem.

How do I **properly terminate** my Web App?

Comment: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2) say _"If the app shuts down unexpectedly, StopAsync might not be called. Therefore, any methods called or operations conducted in StopAsync might not occur."_ - I'm guessing that closing the browser window counts as an 'unexpected' shutdown?

Comment: @stuartd you guessed correctly, that is indeed the case.

Answer (score 8):

I have found the solution. First, I shall quote myself:

> I also noticed a little IIS Express tray icon which lists any apps I've ran and it has a Stop button which doesn't seem to do anything. I assume IIS Express is here simply acting as some kind of a proxy.

Actually that right there is the way to gracefully stop your Kestrel app which is hosted under IIS Express (which is a default option in VS).

Apparently, my IIS Express had a... "hickup", and the Stop command didn't work - there was no error message, simply nothing happened. After closing all the VS instances and killing dotnet.exe process in Task Manager I opened up the solution again and was finally able to stop the app.

Comment: I am not so sure why this was such a challenge for me to figure out (i.e. how to stop site running in Visual Studio 2019), but until I  came across this answer I did not have it figured out.

Answer (score 6):

I am adding an "answer" to supplement the answer given by @bokibeg. To stop a project running in iis in Visual Studio 2019 go to your system tray and right click on the iis express icon. Then select the project that is running. A menu will pop up with a button to stop site.
 [image]

Comment: Interestingly, I just noticed after stopping the site using this method (I am using Visual Studio 2019 working on am ASP.NET Core 3.1 project) the stop button now appears (which is what I have become accustomed to in older versions of Visual Studio).